# ADFS - WID services still on the server after migration to SQL database

Tags: migration, adfs

I took over an ADFS environment when the former ADFS engineer suddenly quit. Before he went he migrated the ADFS from using WID to using a SQL database on a separate SQL database server instead.
But, I can see that the WID service(Windows internal database) still remains on the ADFS servers and that it is still in a "running" state.

Shouldn't these WID components be removed when the migration to a SQL database has been completed?
Shouldn't it be very bad to keep these WID services in place and in a running state, while the ADFS is configured to use the SQL database.?

I thought the last step of a migration to a SQL database included the step to remove the WID(Windows Internal Database) services?
Or do ADFS need to still have the WID service in place to be able to connect towards the SQL database(located on a separate SQL server)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall the WID DB sources after the migration make sure the event logs has the event:100 after the service or the server restart.

confirm the configuration db connections

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace root/ADFS -class SecurityTokenService
```

confirm the current data source- it should be your sql data instance with the db name.

Also confirm your Artifact DB configuration

```
Get-ADFSproperties | fl artifactdbconnection
```

It should  have similar db source.

Uninstall the WID DB sources once the above steps are confirmed.
https://crmguyblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/16/how-to-delete-adfs-windows-internal-database-without-access-credentials/